# Javascript problem I'm trying to extract a string from a textarea

Tags: javascript, regex, match

This is my code:

```
        var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
        var string = input.toString();

        var m = new RegExp('Stipendio' + '(.*?)' + 'D', 'gm');
        var match = string.match(m);
```

I've to extract this string:

**Stipendio** + some text some text some text + **D**

Hi, I'm trying to extract a string from a textarea, but my var match is always null!

where am i wrong? In another script it works perfectly.

thanks

Comment: Your code is ok, maybe your input is wrong. Just a guess, is your element id really "input"?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your input string is `Stipendio + some text some text some text + D`, as you stated in your question.

Your RegExp is faulty (your two `+` were concatenating the strings, they were not actually part of the RegExp, and the `g` RegExp flag was not suitable here).

Your [RegExp can be created in several ways](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

- `new RegExp(/Stipendio \+ (.*?) \+ D/m);`
- `new RegExp(/Stipendio \+ (.*?) \+ D/, "m");`
- `new RegExp("Stipendio \\+ (.*?) \\+ D", "m");` (double escaping `\\` needed)

You could also use it directly in `.match()` like this: `string.match(/Stipendio \+ (.*?) \+ D/m)`

*hhh* was right when saying that [your use of `.toString()` is superfluous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61988908/13486720).

Altogether, your code could be:

```js
const string = document.getElementById("input").value;
const m = new RegExp("Stipendio \\+ (.*?) \\+ D", "m");
const match_result = string.match(m);
console.log(match_result === null ? null : match_result[1]);
```

```html
<textarea id="input">Stipendio + some text some text some text + D</textarea>
```